# using asp.net ado to update excel sheet

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, sql-update, ado.net

when i try to update data in the sheet this happens
error message :

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

```
    Dim excomand As String = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET name = @EXNAME  WHERE id = @EXID"
    Dim comand As New OleDbCommand(excomand, conn)
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXID", TextBox1.Text)
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXNAME", TextBox2.Text)
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("EXPHONE", TextBox3.Text)
```

this is my code

when i use the update with plain text it works but if i use parameters the error occur

Comment: Suspect the use of Parameters.AddWithValue() might be the cause here, will be in all likelihood doing an un-intended type conversion for you.  You are much better off using the Parameters.Add() method where it takes a data type parameter.  Would also suggest rather than just using Texbox1.Text etc, you might be better off putting these values into temporary vars of the correct type allowing some level of validation before executing your update

Comment: You also don't show the connection string being used here. I suspect you using the ms-access data engine, and that means you not only require the access database engine to be installed, but you probably require a x64 bit, since that's what most web sites require. Are you able to query the spreadsheet ok as opposed to updating? I mean, if you can't simple read the sheet, then FOR SURE you not going to update it, right??? So, it is not clear if you can even connect to the sheet, let alone start to do updates. I would verify that you can connect and read the sheet. And provide connection details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.